# How to kill applications like on Windows?

Tags: command-line, kill

I looked it up on google but I didn't find anything helpful.

Anyway, I was playing Crysis 2 (with PlayOnLinux) and the game crashed, but I could't kill the process, I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> but nothing but the game appeared on the screen, I had to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and finish the session, also losing all my work.

On Windows there's the Windows Key (which opens the Unity Panel), but I can't do anything. And there's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> which opens all the processes (on Windows) but the terminal doesn't show up on me (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), I can't kill any process.

Any help?

Comment: you could also change workspace and then open up a terminal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My favorite way to do that is

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Then when you're logged back in run
`ps aux | grep program` keep in mind that *program* should be replaced with the filename of the executable. In your case `ps aux | grep wine`, then you should see something like this:

```
david     1234  0.0  0.0 1595676 2700 ?        Sl   16:12   0:00 wine cmd.exe
```

Where it says cmd.exe yours will be the exe of your game. To kill the process

`kill 1234` 1234 being the Process ID that the previous command gave you; then
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this CTRL+ALT+F1. But instead of "ps aux" isn't easier "ps -A"? And BTW I can't see all processes. How to scroll the page up?

Comment: @Amanda `ps -A` doesn't give you enoufgh details when its a wine program but if its a native program and theres only one running sure. If I understand the issue of "can't see all processes" are you using the grep part of that command.

Comment: grep? :O What's that?

Comment: Grep is nice tool that sorts the output of a program so when you run `ps aux` you pipe it with a `|` to grep `grep wine` so `ps aux | grep wine`

Comment: keep in mind that if you turned your computer off that would have solved your problem so at this point if you run that it probably won't show anything. If you want to test it you could always to it with a working program; gedit should be safe to test on.

Comment: No, the actual name of the process was crysis2.exe (if I recall).
So can you answer how to see all processes? Not even with "ps aux" I can see all of them. There's a way, I just don't know how.

Comment: I prefer `pgrep -f name` to `ps aux| grep name`. And if you want to "see" all processes just pipe ps output to less, `ps -efl|less`.

Comment: yes if you want to see all processes `ps aux | less` is the best way to do that

Comment: So, I did what you guys told me, and I kept pressing ENTER till "END" shows up, now I can't type any command on CTRL+ALT+F1!

Comment: press q to quit

Comment: OK guys you saved my life! I owe you my kidneys now!
So I decided to "ps -A | less", and the pressing ENTER was correct so, everything's fine now!

Comment: If my answer answered your question be sure to accept it as your answer and welcome to StackExchange and AskUbuntu

Comment: Yes. Just next time = specify EVERYTHING to new users like me. I would've rebooted again if the "q to quit" wasn't told or the ENTER thing, specially. Thank to you all.

Answer (score 4):

In that case you could try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Then login with your user name and password and type `top`. Then you can choose to kill the program by typing `kill PIDNR` where PIDNR is the process id number of the program.

Get back into graphical mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

By the way, **htop** is an advanced version of top. You can install it easily (see next command) and you can call it simply by typing `htop` in a commandline. Is has a lot of functions.

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

As an alternative, some people also use `xkill` and then point at the program (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1812120). Very easy.

Comment: Thanks! But you didn't tell me about the CRTL+ALT+F7 so I had to restart my PC hahaha.

Comment: @Amanda I hoped you used `reboot now` and not a forced reboot.

Comment: Yes, I rebooted via command.

Comment: Hi Amanda, sorry for that. Indeed you can get back into graphical mode using (CTRL+) ALT+F7. I will update the answer. Did you try htop?

Comment: +1 htop is much better than top is much easier than ps aux | etc.

Comment: @Amanda: Without knowing your PC setup we don't know which F# will take you back to your graphics session. ALT-F5 and ALT-F7 are just the most likely ones to try.